# Use jQuery to unbind a click handler that wasn't added with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to use jQuery to remove a click event handler that wasn't added with jQuery.  For example:

```
<a onclick="alert('This was set by onclick.')" href="#">Click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").unbind(); // Why isn't this working?
    $("a").click(function(event){
      alert("This was set by jquery click.");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Is this possible?  `$("a").unbind()` isn't working.  The above code displays both `alert()` windows and not just the one added by jQuery.  I think `unbind()` only unbinds handlers which were bound with `bind()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `removeAttr` instead:

```
$('a').removeAttr('onclick');
```